# Given three values, how can I change one value to guarantee it is not equal to one of the other values?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 3 values; x, y, and z.
Each value can only be a single digit (0-9).
I know that x and y are different.
I don't know if y and z are different or the same.
I don't know if x and z are already different or the same.

I want to change the value of z (using x and/or y) in such a way that guarantees it is not the same as x.

However the value of z must be changed in such a way that given x and y (and the new z) the original value of z can be calculated.

Here is an example formula that doesn't work:

```
z = z + (y - x) % 10
```

I can show this doesn't work with the following values.

```
x = 5, y = 0, z = 0
```

As z becomes 5 which is the same as x.

Is it possible to come up with a formula that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done if you need to recover $z$.  As you know that $x \neq y$ there are $900$ input triplets $(x,y,z)$ that are possible, $10$ choices for $x, 9$ choices for $y$ and $10$ for $z$.  Even if you allow the new $z$ to equal $y$, there are only $810$ output triplets available, so there will be cases where more than one input triplet is mapped to the same output triplet.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible, how would you distinguish between  the following cases (the values give $x,y,z$):

$0,1,0$

$0,1,1$

$0,1,2$

$0,1,3$

$0,1,4$

$0,1,5$

$0,1,6$

$0,1,7$

$0,1,8$

$0,1,9$

Each of these cases is going to have an output between:

$0,1,1$

$0,1,2$

$0,1,3$

$0,1,4$

$0,1,5$

$0,0,6$

$0,1,7$

$0,1,8$

$0,1,9$

So there are nine inputs and eight outputs, therefore two different inputs are going to give the same output, we won't be able to distinguish them, which is equivalent to not being able to distinguish the value of $z$.

Comment: OP did promise us that $x \neq y$, but the point is still valid if you just change all the $y$'s to $1$